# Include field(s) from another module in SugarCRM Dashlet

Tags: module, sugarcrm

I have created a custom module that tracks callbacks pertaining to a specific account. I need to know how to build a dashlet that can pull that account information based on the foreign key given. Can someone help me understand how to modify a dashlet to reference data from another module?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the dashlet definitions in modules/Home/dashlets folder. What kind on view you want to achieve will depend how to do it. I allways used custom html view that i populated with data using php. Another option is to use generate listview functions and query's to utilize the SugarCRM function.

There is no simple explanation here.